# Java Regex Starts With and Ends With Condition Replacer

Tags: java, regex, string

I have lines at my text as like:

```
=== Keno ===
```

I want to do that `if a line starts with = and ends with =` I want to put a new line character and an under score. I mean that:

```
=== Keno ===
_
```

I want to do it with regex using Java. How can I do that?

**PS:** Input is not a single line. I want to check each line at input whether matches with my need.

Comment: When will the day come people start using regex for what it's good for? `String#startsWith()` and `String#endsWith()` seems not fancy enough? Also, replacing is nothing genuinely regex-y, they are about *matching* stuff.

Comment: Input is not a single line. I want to check each line at input string.

Comment: Iterating is not possible?

Comment: I want a fast solution. Because I will run an NLP algorithm at a big corpus.

Comment: Then you should skip regex all the more - simulating a whole NFA for such a simple task?

Comment: This maybe the out of scope but is there any performance benchmark for using regex or not for same operations at Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give the following a try:

```
String s = "=== Kendo ===";
String repl = "$1" + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "_";
String newString = s.replaceAll("(?m)^(=.*=)$", repl); // $1\n_
```

This also works with multi line strings, e.g:

```
=== foo ===
one
two
=== bar ===
three
four
```

Would become:

```
=== foo ===
_
one
two
=== bar ===
_
three
four
```

In which case it somewhat makes sense to use `replaceAll`/`regex` for this, if you are working on single strings though, I'd say regex is overkill.

## Update:

I did some quick testing for regex vs noon regex and in all the tests I did the regex approach came out slower. This might change depending on the input data obviously, all the different inputs I had. Feel free to test for yourself, the code I used is listed below (albeit with different/larger test data).

I won't post any results as I haven't done any extensive testing, but for no input did regex come out faster than the non regex variety, and I'm sure you could optimize the `replaceAllNoRegex` method further.

**Edit:**
Added a third option: `replaceAllIndex` this is even faster, note that I haven't extensively tested this so there might be bugs, but using indexOf or even looping trough all the chars one at the time is even faster than the tokenizer it seems.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "=== Etiam ===\neu\nmagna\nsit\namet\norci\nrutrum\nfeugiat\n\n=== Nunc ===\nurna\nlorem,\negestas\net\nvarius\nfermentum,\nconsectetur\nsed\nmauris\n";

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        replaceAllNoRegex(s);

    System.out.println("Tokens: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));

    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        replaceAllIndex(s);
    
    System.out.println("Index: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
    
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        s.replaceAll("(?m)^(=.*?=)$", "$1\n_");

    System.out.println("Regex: " + (System.currentTimeMillis()-start));
}

public static String replaceAllNoRegex(String s) {
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,"\n");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String next;
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        next = (String) st.nextElement();
        sb.append(next);
        if (next.startsWith("=") && next.endsWith("=")) {
            sb.append("\n_");
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String replaceAllIndex(String s) {
    int index = 0, indexEnd, indexStart = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while (index == 0 || (index = s.indexOf("\n=", index)) != -1) {
        indexEnd = s.indexOf("\n",index+2);
        if (indexEnd != -1 && s.charAt(indexEnd-1) == '=') {
            sb.append(s.substring(indexStart,indexEnd));
            sb.append("\n_\n");
            indexStart = indexEnd + 1;
        }
        index = indexEnd+1;
    }
    sb.append(s.substring(indexStart));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: instead of \n you may be better off with System.getProperty("line.separator")

Answer (score 1):

If you really want regex then this should work:

```
str = "=== Keno ===";
String repl = str.replaceFirst("(?m)^(=.*?=)$", "$1\n_");
```

OR using `System.getProperty("line.separator")`:

```
String repl = str.replaceFirst("(?m)^(=.*?=)$", "$1" + 
                                               System.getProperty("line.separator") + "_");
```

Comment: +1 I would use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` instead of `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this.

Checking if the line starts and ends with `=` and if true replace the line

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String line : content.split("\n")){
    if(line.startsWith("=") && line.endsWith("=")){
        line = line.append("\n_");
    }
    sb.append(line);
}
content = sb.toString();
```

However if you insist on the regex, then the condition would look like this

```
if(line.matches("\=.*\=")){
    // then..
}
```